# View email before sending in .net

Tags: c#, .net, html-email

I have a method that I use on a button click to send an email and it works but is there a way to have complete the action and create the email but just have it come up to view before its sent? I am going to be adding attachments and important information that needs to be correct before sending, is there a way to do this without any kind of add-ons? or if so then please inform me of those add-ons, only one user will need to perform this function so it should be ok for one time install.

Here is my code so far:

```
        protected void Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string fromEmail = "test@testers.com.com";
        const string toEmail = "testers3@test.com";
        const string bodyString = "Hello Everyone,";

        var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail);
        message.Subject = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + " SummarySheet";
        message.Body = bodyString;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        var smtp = new SmtpClient("****.*****.com");
        smtp.Send(message);

    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: winforms, wpf or web?

Comment: The email is your body string... what exactly do you want to preview?

Comment: @Softwarehuset, .net application

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I want to preview the email before it is sent. So like you would go into outlook and click new email and edit it before it is sent.

Comment: @CSharpDev4Evr .net application is everything that uses the framework --> console, winforms, web mvc/web forms, wpf etc.

If you want to know how to preview then we need to know what platform you are developing on. if its web then you could put your body into an iframe. if its a winforms app then you could use a webbrowser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a `MailItem`, taken directly from the Outlook Interop;

```
MailItem email = (MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
email.Subject = subject;
email.HTMLBody = body;
email.To = string.Format("{0};{1}", "xxx@yyy.com", "zzz@yyy.com");
email.Display();
```

I don't think you can spoof the **From** field with this method though (there's no From property on the MailItem, so you can't do it directly anyway), it will populate the From field with the person/account currently logged in to Outlook. Spoofing can get quite complicated anyway (mail server config needs to be taken into account, possible authentication issues, etc.) and given the comments it doesn't sound like you want/need to do that, so this should work.

Comment: require outlook which could be a problem in some cases and you are risking your users are sending duplicate mails ( both in outlook and in your application) But it works :)